# How do I align 3 spans but push one a bit lower

Tags: html, css

I have a `<span>` that is a container to 3 child spans.  I would like to lower the middle span (the circle) 1px or 2px.  Or alternatively, raise the left and right span 1 or 2px.

However, changing one thing affects the other.  How can I lower the circle or raise up the text?

```css
.time {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 130px; 
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #006600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.case {
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span class="time">9:00 AM - 1:00 PM</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span style="">9am-1pm ZM: Frank Rizzo vs. Holiday Star Inn, LLC, et al.</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

with css3 nth-child you can control the span.

```css
.time {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #006600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.case {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.SpanWrap span:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="SpanWrap">
  <span class="time">9:00 AM - 1:00 PM</span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span style="">9am-1pm ZM: Frank Rizzo vs. Holiday Star Inn, LLC, et al.</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.time {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 130px; 
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #006600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.case {
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span class="time">9:00 AM - 1:00 PM</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span style="">9am-1pm ZM: Frank Rizzo vs. Holiday Star Inn, LLC, et al.</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a display flex to your parent element and the margin within the child containing the circle will control the circle element.

Alternatively with display **flex** approach you could also do an `align-items:` ***flex-start*** or ***center*** on the *parent*, then on your *child* circle element, do `align-self: flex-end;` and it would have a similar effect, aligning the other two spans a bit higher than the one with `align-self: flex-end;`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.time {
  width: 130px; 
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #006600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.case {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="parent">
  <span class="time">9:00 AM - 1:00 PM</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span style="">9am-1pm ZM: Frank Rizzo vs. Holiday Star Inn, LLC, et al.</span>
</span>
```

**Using `align-self` on child circle element:**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.time {
  width: 130px; 
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #006600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 26px;
  /* margin-top: 7px; <--- no longer needed */
  margin-right: 20px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.case {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="parent">
  <span class="time">9:00 AM - 1:00 PM</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span style="">9am-1pm ZM: Frank Rizzo vs. Holiday Star Inn, LLC, et al.</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` accept pixel value (and length in general) so use it to adjust the alignment like you want

```css
.time {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 130px; 
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #006600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: -6px; /* here */
}

.case {
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span class="time">9:00 AM - 1:00 PM</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span style="">9am-1pm ZM: Frank Rizzo vs. Holiday Star Inn, LLC, et al.</span>
</span>
```